# Java ArrayList strings lengths printing

Tags: java, string, arraylist, string-length

My excercise is:

> Create the method lengths that gets a list of String variables as a parameter and returns an ArrayList that contains the lengths of the Strings in the same order as the original list.

And my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for (String item : strings) {
            System.out.print(item.length());
        }
        return list;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        list.add("Dog");
        list.add("Elephant");
        list.add("Aligator");
        list.add("Parrot");

        ArrayList<Integer> stringLenghts = lengths(list);
        System.out.println(stringLenghts);

    }
}
```

And this program outputs

> 3386[]

Instead of

> [3, 3, 8, 6]

Any idea where I do a mistake?

Comment: I don't know who down voted this,  but IMO,  this is a fine question.  Just because he's a beginner does not make it a bad question.

Comment: @mmaceachran And I don't know who upvotes badly researched questions with are no help for anyone else than OP (and this is not what Stack Overflow is here for).

Comment: @Tom I'm sorry, I'm not into StackOverflow yet. Any helpful advices how to use it would be nice for me.

Comment: No worries, as you can see in the upvotes, people don't care what the purpose of Stack Overflow is. All they care about is spoon feeding and farming reputation. And since you've registered today, you should have read what you need to know. Or you actively ignored the help center and the tour.

Comment: @Tom so what's your suggestions about making topics on this site?

Comment: My suggestion is that you stop ignoring that help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `lengths()` method, you are simply printing the length values. 
But you are NOT adding the lengths to the `ArrayList` i.e., your `stringLenghts` list is empty (so printing as `[]` empty array), so change your code as shown below:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String item : strings) {
            list.add(item.length());//add length to list
        }
        return list;
}
```

Comment: So simple :) Worked fine of course, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

public static ArrayList<Integer> lengths(ArrayList<String> strings) {
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (String item : strings) {
        list.add(item.length());
    }
    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    list.add("Dog");
    list.add("Elephant");
    list.add("Aligator");
    list.add("Parrot");

    ArrayList<Integer> stringLenghts = lengths(list);
    System.out.println(stringLenghts);

}
}
```

EDIT: In the lengths method, the list is being created but you are not adding any items to it. Now in the code abode for (String item : strings) { list.add(item.length()); } This adds the length of each string to the new ArrayList which you will return to the main method for printing.

Thanks

Comment: In the lengths method, the list is being created but you are not adding any items to it. Now in the code abode 
       for (String item : strings) {
           list.add(item.length());
        }
This adds the length of each string to the new ArrayList which you will return to the main method for printing.

Comment: Thanks your for your help. Worked fine!

Comment: Edit your answer and add that comment into the answer @AritraChatterjee

Answer (score 2):

You need correct this body of cycle and add here the numbers

```
list.add(item.length());
```

between brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Initially you are printing the length of each string from the loop

```
for(String item : strings) {
     System.out.print(item.length());
}
```

which **outputs : 3386** (no new line because of print)
After this empty ArrayList is printed because you are returning the empty arrayList object.

```
System.out.println(stringLenghts);
```

which **outputs : [ ]**

***Solution :*** 
You have to replace 
`System.out.print(item.length());`
with
`list.add(item.length());`